# Selenium in Kotlin => Actions not available

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, kotlin, action

I'm trying to context click a button by Selenium using Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA. I need to select the first 10 lines of a table, right click them and click an entry in the context menu.
Therefore I need an Actions object-already here the Problem starts! "Actions" is written in red color, IntelliJ refuses to import "org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions" It says "Unresolved reference: Actions". But there must be a way to do it! I get desperate more and more, please help me!

This is my test class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.testng.annotations.*
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent

class BatchProcessTest {

    init{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\<path to chromedriver>\chromedriver.exe")
}

private val driver = ChromeDriver() as WebDriver
private val testBase : TestBase = TestBase(driver)
private var isTestClassInitialized = false

@BeforeTest
private fun initiateTestSuite(){
    testBase.startTestObject()
    testBase.openWebPage()
    testBase.loginTestUserUsingCredentials(<username>,<userpassword>)
    testBase.waitForMilliseconds(5000)
    isTestClassInitialized = true
}

@Test
private fun testUnderConstruction() {

    while(!isTestClassInitialized){
        testBase.waitForMilliseconds(1000)
    }
    setPreconds()
}

private fun setPreconds(){

    prepareACategoryWithAtLeastTenEntriesAsK1()
}

private fun prepareACategoryWithAtLeastTenEntriesAsK1(){

    createAPattern(<patternName>, <patternRule>)
    executePatterns()
    testBase.getButtonByCaption("Back").click()
    changeIntoCategory(<name of category K0>)
    moveTenOfTheMovedEntriesIntoK1(<name of category K1>)


}

private fun createAPattern(text : String, category: String){

    val settingsButton = driver.findElements(By.className("lm-button")).get(0)
    settingsButton.click()
    testBase.waitForMilliseconds(3000)

    val addButton = testBase.getButtonByCaption("Add")
    addButton.click()

    val patternTextField = testBase.getTextFieldByLabelCaption("Pattern name")
    patternTextField.sendKeys(text)

    testBase.selectComboboxElementUsingLabelCaption(category,"Pattern name")
    testBase.waitForMilliseconds(1000)

    val saveButton = testBase.getButtonByCaption("Save")
    saveButton.click()
}

private fun executePatterns(){
    testBase.getButtonByCaption("Execute").click()

}

private fun changeIntoCategory(categoryName : String){
    testBase.getButtonByCaption(name of category K1).click()
    testBase.waitForMilliseconds(3000)
}

private fun moveTenOfTheMovedEntriesIntoK1(categoryName : String) {

val action = Actions(driver) 
val allLines = driver.findElements(By.className("v-grid-row"))
action.click(allLines.get(0)).perform()
var i = 0

while (i < 11) {
    i++
    action.click(allLines.get(i)).perform()
}

action.contextClick().perform()
```

}

And this is my TestBase class (helper class):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

class TestBase(driver: WebDriver) {

val driver: WebDriver = driver

fun startTestObject(): Boolean {

    val batchProcessBuilder = ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "startTheTestObject.bat")
    batchProcessBuilder.start()
    return true
}

fun openWebPage() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/kotlin/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(<URL of Web application>)
    driver.manage().window().maximize()
    waitForMilliseconds(5000)
}

fun loginTestUserUsingCredentials(usrName: String, usrPassword: String) {
    val userNameField = getTextFieldByLabelCaption("Username")
    val userPasswordField = getTextFieldByLabelCaption("Password")
    val loginButton = getButtonByCaption("Login")

    userNameField.sendKeys(usrName)
    userPasswordField.sendKeys(usrPassword)

    loginButton.click()
}

fun waitForMilliseconds(milliseconds: Long) {
    Thread.sleep(milliseconds)
}

fun getButtonByCaption(caption: String): WebElement {
    val allButtonsOnSettingsPage = driver.findElements(By.className("lm-button"))
    val filteredButtons = allButtonsOnSettingsPage.filter { it.text.contains(caption) }
    return filteredButtons.get(0)
}

fun getTextFieldByLabelCaption(caption: String): WebElement {

    val allFormLayoutsOnThisPage = driver.findElements(By.className("v-formlayout-row"))
    val filteredFormLayouts = allFormLayoutsOnThisPage.filter { it.findElement(By.className("v-formlayout-captioncell")).text.contains(caption) }
    val searchedTextField = filteredFormLayouts.get(0).findElement(By.className("v-textfield"))
    return searchedTextField
}

fun selectComboboxElementUsingLabelCaption(optionText: String, labelCaption: String) {
    val combobox = getComboboxdByLabelCaption(labelCaption)
    val window = driver.findElement(By.className("v-window"))

    combobox.click()
    waitForMilliseconds(2000)

    var i = 0
    var isEntryFound = false

    while (!isEntryFound){

        var actualElementText = driver.findElements(By.className("gwt-MenuItem")).get(i).text
        isEntryFound = actualElementText.equals(optionText)
        combobox.sendKeys(Keys.UP)
        waitForMilliseconds(700)
        i++
    }

    combobox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
    waitForMilliseconds(1000)
}

fun getComboboxdByLabelCaption(caption: String): WebElement {

    waitForMilliseconds(2000)
    val allFormLayoutsOnThisPage = driver.findElements(By.className("v-formlayout-row"))
    val filteredFormLayouts = allFormLayoutsOnThisPage.filter { it.findElement(By.className("v-formlayout-captioncell")).text.contains(caption) }
    val searchedComboboxElement = filteredFormLayouts.get(0).findElement(By.className("v-filterselect-input"))
    return searchedComboboxElement
}
}
```

This is the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>KotlinTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>KotlinTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>KotlinTest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.2-4</kotlin.version>
        <testng.version>6.10</testng.version>
        <selenium.version>3.8.1</selenium.version>
        <selenium.server.standalone.version>3.8.1</selenium.server.standalone.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
         <version>${selenium-server-standalone.version}</version>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show the whole class please, with imports? Also where does that "driver" variable come from?

Comment: Hey Jan, sure! Here you are. Please bear with me that I used to remove some parmeters (expressions in <>) because it's a customer project.

Comment: Hm seems to work for me. You have a typo in the "while" loop where it states "action(s)" instead of "action" other than that it is green in my Intellij. Are the Selenium libs properly referenced in your project tree? What do you use for dependency management - maven, gradle, kobalt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for checking the code. The typos are removed and I found the reason for my problem. A missing repository caused the error:

```
    <repositories> 
      <repository> 
         <id>jcenter</id> 
         <url>jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </repository> 
    </repositories>
```

Be careful copying this from the internet- it can have curious effects in the POM. (Might be caused by destructed characters) Thanks for your help! – AcMuD 1 min ago   edit